# Adding many checkboxes in R Manipulate as a list/vector

Tags: r, user-interface, plot, statistics

I'm using `{manipulate}` to add a number of check-boxes to the plot - one for each line that is being drawn. Since the number required is not pre-defined I'm trying to figure a way out to pass all checkboxes as a vector or a list to the `manipulate` function.
The documentation seems to hint something :

> manipulate(`_expr`, ...)
>
> _expr : Expression to evalulate.
>
> ...  : One or more named control arguments (i.e. slider, picker, checkbox, or button), **or a list containing named controls.**

I think the way out would be to pass a list of as many checkboxes as is required. But how exactly should that be carried out?

Answer (score 1):

The following example should do what you want:

```
# Define function for ploting
example <- function(...){
  plot(cars)
  i <- 1
  for (my.control in list(...)) {
    if (my.control) abline(0, i)
    i <- i+1
  }
}

# Define your controls
custom.args <- list()
for (i in 1:5) {
  custom.args <- append(custom.args, list(checkbox(FALSE, paste("Ceckbox", i))))
}
names(custom.args) <- paste("checkbox", 1:5, sep="")

# Pass everything to manipulate
library(manipulate)
manipulate(
  eval(parse(text=sprintf('example(%s)', 
                          paste(names(custom.args), collapse=","))
             )),
  custom.args)
```

I don't know if there is a cleaner way to pass control values to plotting function, but at least this works.